# What is the meaning of a nonnegative definite function?

Tags: positive-definite

I know non-negative definiteness for a matrix, but I am reading some notes that use it for a function $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I am not *sure* since it doesnt' say so explictily, but I inferred that the definition is something along the lines of

$$\sum_{i, j = 1}^N a_i a_j f(t_i - t_j) \ge 0, \ \forall t_i, t_j \in Z, a_i, a_j \in \mathbb{R}$$
where $a_i, a_j$ are real, $N$ is some integer, and $t_i, t_j$ are integers as well.

My questions are:

- Is this definition accurate?
- Why is it not the same as the definition for a matrix? (In particular, the $a_i a_j$ are not $a_i^2$).
- What special properties do such functions have? Or, to make it less general: how do the properties of such functions relate to the corresponding properties that the nonnegative definite matrices have.

Comment: An $n \times n$ symmetric matrix $M$ is nonnegative definite if $a^\top M a = \sum_{i,j=1}^N a_i a_j M_{ij} \ge 0$ for all vectors $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. This condition resembles the definition you've given for functions, although I cannot comment on the accurateness of the definition.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function for the usual definition.  The key requirement is that the inequality holds true _for all_ choices of $N$, of the $t_i$ and the $a_i$.